# Half vertical part of Sprite shows through above layered Sprite

Tags: quartz-composer

I have two Sprites, where one is layer 3 and the other layer 4. For some reason the lower vertical half of the layer 4 Sprite hides behind the layer 3 Sprite. As images show.

[image]

[image]

This is my QC composition:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a result of depth testing being on. If you don't want the position of the Sprite to determine the on screen visibility try setting Depth Testing to None on your Sprites.